# .firstChild retornando o filho errado

Tags: javascript

O Erro é bem simples mas não conseguir encontrar.

Eu estou aprendendo a utilizar a DOM CORE API.
Criei uma DIV, e dentro coloquei uma UL.
Estou alertando quem é o primeiro filho da DIV, e o resultado está dando `OBJECT TEXT`. invés de dar `OBJECT UL LIST`.
segue o código.

```
<html lang="pt-BR">
    <head>
        <title>Dom Core Api</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <script src="js/testDom.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
      <div>
          <ul><li>Rodrigo</li>
            <li>Robson</li>
          </ul>
      </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Código javaScript

```
window.onload = function() {
    var div = document.getElementsByTagName("div").item(0);
    alert(div.firstChild);
}
```

[image: Resultado no Navegador]

Comment: o post foi Ajustado

Comment: Melhorou bastante ajustado.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

O que procuras é o [`.firstElementChild`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ParentNode/firstElementChild) que te dá o primeiro filho que é um elemento. Quando usas somente `.firstChild` ele vai dar-te o text em branco e a quebra de linha que tens no HTML.

Repara neste exemplo:

```js
var div1 = document.getElementsByTagName('div').item(0);
console.log(div1.firstChild, div1.firstElementChild); // #text, ul

var div2 = document.getElementsByTagName('div').item(1);
console.log(div2.firstChild, div2.firstElementChild); // ul, ul
```

```html
<div>
    <ul>
        <li>A</li>
        <li>B</li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div><ul><li>A</li><li>B</li></ul></div>
```

No primeiro exemplo dá `#text`, mas no segundo não pois não há espaço entre o HTML de `div` e `ul`.

Podes ainda testar o `.nodeType` que vai confirmar as diferênças:

```
console.log(div1.firstChild.nodeType, div1.firstElementChild.nodeType); // 3, 1
console.log(div2.firstChild.nodeType, div2.firstElementChild.nodeType); // 1, 1
```

Comment: É verdade agora deu certo, eu estava estudando pelo aulas do canal do XTI, e lá ele fazia .firstChild e retornava o elemento normalmente, mesmo com o espaço.

Mas valeu ai, resolveu o problema.

Comment: @RodrigoJacinto se a resposta te atendeu, pode então marcá-la como aceita.

Comment: Só pra alertar, até o IE8 ainda precisa usar o método antigo, verificando o tipo de cada node pra ver se é element ou não.

Comment: @bfavaretto bem visto. Eu já deixei o IE8 para trás, mas pode haver ainda quem use.

Comment: Eu também já abandonei. Foi quase tão bom quanto o dia em que eu disse adeus ao IE6 :)

Comment: @bfavaretto haha :)

Comment: Mas o navegador que eu uso é Google Chrome, não o IE8